# Performance difference between set::find and <algorithm> find

Tags: c++, stl, time-complexity

According to [cplusplus.com](http://cplusplus.com), `[set::find][2]` time complexity is logarithmic in size and `[find function in algorithm library][3]` is up to linear in size.

```
    set::find(item)
    find(begin(set),end(set),item)
```

I am wondering how these two `find` methods perform differently in terms of time complexity.

Comment: Didn't you answer your own question?

Comment: @Steyrix no. I know they perform differently, I want to know why.

Comment: std::find is generic and does not assume sorted data like set::find can assume. Something like std::lower_bound is more comparable to how set::find works

Comment: "time complexity is logarithmic in size and find function in algorithm library is up to linear in size" says it all.

Comment: The reason `set::find()` has different complexity than the algorithm `find()` is that `set::find()` can take advantage of features unique to a `std::set`.    The algorithm `find()` needs to accept iterators from any type of container, which may not have the exploitable characteristics of `std::set`.

Answer (score 3):

`std::find` is just a linear search as it assumes nothing on the iterators.

`std::set::find` utilizes set's tree structure to achieve log-fast performance.

Comment: so this set::find kind of performing binary search while std::find is just linear search, right?

Comment: @prhmma exactly. Most operations on `std::set` are like binary search or other methods that utilize the fact that set is sorted.

Answer (score 2):

They perform differently exactly as you said (logarithmic vs linear). The reason is that `std::find` only has access to the iterators of the container and only use the operations that are possible for them (i.e. increasing, decreasing, dereferencing...). That `set::find` can be so fast is due to the tree-structure of the internal implementation of `set`. A structure on that `std::find` has no access to, so it cannot be that fast.

Actually, I think that the "linear in size" also applies to the number of comparisons and stepping of the iterator. If those operations are expensive (not that uncommon for comparison while increasing of iterators is normally constant time, but I think for set-iterators that is actually only amortized constant and up to logarithmic in the worst case), then the time complexity will also suffer. The `set::find` has the same problem, but to a lesser extent, since it already does less comparisons.

It would be possible to make the necessary information about the map available to the iterators and adapt the `std::find` algorithm for these types of iterators. But that is by no means trivial and also wouldn't be worth the effort at all. But for easier adaptions this is indeed done. For example `std::binary_search` is faster for random access iterators.